# orchard IRepository.Create error

Tags: orchardcms-1.9, orchardcms-1.10

I'm working on
http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-9

my orchard version is 1.9

OrderRecord.cs

```
public class OrderRecord
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Vat { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<OrderDetailRecord> Details { get; private set; }
        public virtual string PaymentServiceProviderResponse { get; set; }
        public virtual string PaymentReference { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? PaidAt { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CompletedAt { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? CancelledAt { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal Total
        {
            get { return SubTotal + Vat; }
            private set { }
        }

        public virtual string Number
        {
            get { return (Id + 1000).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
            private set { }
        }

        public OrderRecord()
        {
            Details = new List<OrderDetailRecord>();
        }

        public virtual void UpdateTotals()
        {
            var subTotal = 0m;
            var vat = 0m;

            foreach (var detail in Details)
            {
                subTotal += detail.SubTotal;
                vat += detail.Vat;
            }

            SubTotal = subTotal;
            Vat = vat;
        }
```

No additional content part class because i need to use id and methods are defined in the same class. Field setters that not necessary to create table are defined as private. `Total` and `Number`

Migration.cs

```
 SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("OrderRecord", t => t
                    .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                    .Column<int>("CustomerId", c => c.NotNull())
                    .Column<DateTime>("CreatedAt", c => c.NotNull())
                    .Column<decimal>("SubTotal", c => c.NotNull())
                    .Column<decimal>("Vat", c => c.NotNull())
                    .Column<string>("Status", c => c.WithLength(50).NotNull())
                    .Column<string>("PaymentServiceProviderResponse", c => c.WithLength(null))
                    .Column<string>("PaymentReference", c => c.WithLength(50))
                    .Column<DateTime>("PaidAt", c => c.Nullable())
                    .Column<DateTime>("CompletedAt", c => c.Nullable())
                    .Column<DateTime>("CancelledAt", c => c.Nullable())

                    );
```

Table created correctly with these fields but when i want to create an OrderRecord in OrderService.cs with IRepository.Create (T Entity) method, it sends fields not binded to the table. `Total` and `Number`.

OrderService.cs

```
public OrderRecord CreateOrder(int customerId, IEnumerable<ShoppingCartItem> items)
{

    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

    // Convert to an array to avoid re-running the enumerable
    var itemsArray = items.ToArray();

    if (!itemsArray.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException("Creating an order with 0 items is not supported", "items");

    var order = new OrderRecord
    {
        CreatedAt = _dateTimeService.Now,
        CustomerId = customerId,
        Status = OrderStatus.New
    };

    _orderRepository.Create(order);
```

Last line throws error 
here is error log:

> 2018-04-20 18:37:15,871 [16] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy
>   - Default - An unexpected exception was caught [http://localhost:64607/Orchard.WebShop/Order/Create]
>   NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
>   [Orchard.Webshop.Models.OrderRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO
>   Orchard_Webshop_OrderRecord (CustomerId, CreatedAt, SubTotal, Vat,
>   Status, PaymentServiceProviderResponse, PaymentReference, PaidAt,
>   CompletedAt, CancelledAt, Total, Number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Total'.
>   Invalid column name 'Number'. Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>
>   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
>
>   at
>   NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand
>   insert, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo
>   insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo
>   insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[]
>   fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[]
>   fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object
>   entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean
>   useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean
>   requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object
>   entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean
>   useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean
>   requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object
>   entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source,
>   Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)    at
>   Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Create(T entity) in
>   C:\Users\Selman\Orchard-dev\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 93
>   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Create(T
>   entity) in
>   C:\Users\Selman\Orchard-dev\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 33
>
>   at Orchard.Webshop.Services.OrderService.CreateOrder(Int32 customerId,
>   IEnumerable`1 items) in
>   C:\Users\Selman\Orchard-dev\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Webshop\Services\OrderService.cs:line
>   46    at Orchard.Webshop.Controllers.OrderController.Create() in
>   C:\Users\Selman\Orchard-dev\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Webshop\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line
>   48    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

**Solution**

I found a solution temporarily. I turned `Total` and `Number` fields into to methods `public virtual decimal Total()` and `public virtual string Number()`. It works right now.